# "deprecated" status on Google App Engine Django

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm looking at [Google App Engine Django](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/) on google code but the latest release (May 15/09) has been *deprecated*.

I'd like to know why that is?  Are they discouraging us from using it?  What deprecated it?  Is there a better way to get set up with django?

Comment: Where did you read that it's deprecated?

Comment: When you browse here http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/downloads/list?can=1&q=, each is deprecated, even the most recent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the packaged downloads are recommended by the project's owners -- **deprecated** basically means the same thing as "**NOT** recommended". There have been several changes since the May 15 upload of the last (now-deprecated) downloads, and I imagine the project owners are working to get a new enhanced download rounded up and ready.

Django 1.0 is now natively supported in App Engine (see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) for details) and I imagine the project's owners are simply deciding how best to support their small but important bits of added value on top of that support.  If you DO need such little extras, your best best may be to either wait for a new download to be prepared and blessed, OR try an SVN checkout as explained [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/source/checkout) and see if that meets your needs (possibly w/some tweaking -- be sure to offer the tweaks as a patch to the project owners if you make any!-).

Sounds chaotic...?  Welcome to [open source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)!-)